# Add an event to a listview item when item is a complex layout

Tags: android

I have a listview containing items, each item is a linearLayout with an editText and other components.

Now, I'd like to associate an event to the editText, in particular I need to know if it is modified by the user.

My idea is to create a customAdapter for the listview and then handle the event there...is it the right way to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, creating a custom Adapter would be the way to go.

You can handle the event inside **`getView()`** of your adapter and then use it to respond to events accordingly.

Here is a sample code from this amazing [tutorial](http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/07/16/listview-in-android-using-custom-listadapter-and-viewcache/) :

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

      private int resource;
      private LayoutInflater inflater;
      private Context context;

      public MyListAdapter ( Context ctx, int resourceId, Listobjects) {

            super( ctx, resourceId, objects );
            resource = resourceId;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from( ctx );
      context=ctx;
      }

      @Override
      public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {

            /* create a new view of my layout and inflate it in the row */
            convertView = ( RelativeLayout ) inflater.inflate( resource, null );

            /* Extract the city's object to show */
            City city = getItem( position );

            /* Take the TextView from layout and set the city's name */
            TextView txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cityName);
            txtName.setText(city.getName());

            /* Take the TextView from layout and set the city's wiki link */
            TextView txtWiki = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cityLinkWiki);
            txtWiki.setText(city.getUrlWiki());

            /* Take the ImageView from layout and set the city's image */
            ImageView imageCity = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageCity);
            String uri = "drawable/" + city.getImage();
            int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, context.getPackageName());
            Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
            imageCity.setImageDrawable(image);
            return convertView;
      }
}
```

**[Source for the whole code can be found here](http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/07/16/listview-in-android-using-custom-listadapter-and-viewcache/)**